# Just want to add a darken layer or make the UIImageView darken by Swift

Tags: ios, swift

As people already know that this seems simple but Stackoverflow has no answers for me. Basically I want to make an image darker like the bg image of Beijing ancient building below:

[image]

to make it darker so that the tags on it can be more contrasting obvious.

I tried adding a layer which is one of the answers from Stackoverflow or adding tintColor but none of them worked, is there any method that can really work?  Thank you, guys.

I'm under iOS 13 and swift 5.1

Comment: Overlay a translucent `UIView` with a dark ground - or, reverse the idea, place the translucent `UIImage` over a dark `UIView`

Comment: Add a black view above your imageview and decrease its alpha accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this `UIView` extension to your project

```
extension UIView {
func addoverlay(color: UIColor = .black,alpha : CGFloat = 0.6) {
    let overlay = UIView()
    overlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    overlay.frame = bounds
    overlay.backgroundColor = color
    overlay.alpha = alpha
    addSubview(overlay)
    }
    //This function will add a layer on any `UIView` to make that `UIView` look darkened
}
```

then use it like on any `UIView`(In your Case `yourImageView`)

```
yourImageView.addoverlay()
```

Or you can specify your own overlay color and alpha value

```
yourImageView.addoverlay(color: .blue, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: @Rob, I have edited my answer, thanks for your suggestions :)